# Where are the songs "Daring Escape" and "Mach Running" used in Canabalt?

Tags: canabalt

I've purchased [Canabalt](http://adamatomic.com/canabalt/) multiple times for multiple platforms. Most recently, I purchased it as part of the Humble Bundle for Android #2, which included the soundtrack.

I downloaded the soundtrack, and unzipped it, to find it contained MP3 files for 3 songs:

- RUN!
- Daring Escape
- Mach Runner

Now, the song *RUN!* is very familiar. It's the song playing in the background every single time I play Canabalt. But the other two songs - *Daring Escape* and *Mach Running* - are new to me. I've played Canabalt long enough to run over 13,000 meters, and I've only ever heard *RUN!*

So I'm curious, **where are the other 2 songs used in the game**? If you eventually run far enough will the music change? Or are they used elsewhere? Or were they perhaps written for the game and not used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Android version of Canabalt, the top-right corner of the screen has a music note icon. To the left of this icon is the currently selected music. If you tap the icon, the current music cycles between these three tracks.  I suspect other versions of the game have a similar method of changing music.

Comment: iOS version has the Now Playing song listed in the top right corner. No icon like Android, but clicking on the song name will cycle through the three songs.

Comment: I had no idea that was there! And now it seems so obvious. I guess it's because it doesn't appear while you're actually playing that I didn't see it, because I'm always so quick to jump past the title screen. Thanks for your help.